# Add date modified to file name

Tags: powershell

I would like to add a timestamp to my file with date modified. Current file name could be 'James.txt' and date modified 19/03/2020 11:11AM i would like to change all files in the folder to James_190320201111

Comment: So what have you tried? Give us your code so we can look at it and give you some hints

Comment: "i would like to change all files in the folder to James_190320201111" file names have to be distinct per folder, you can't rename multiple files to be the exact same name

Comment: I guess he meant `$file_ddMMyyyyHHmm` but yeah, 90% of the questions in PS forum show so much lack of research.

Comment: THis Helped but only worked for .jpg files remove .jpg 'Get-ChildItem *.jpg | Rename-Item -newname {$_.LastWriteTime.toString("ddMMyyyyHH.mm") + ".jpg"}'

Comment: `$_.Extension` to get the format and `$_.BaseName` to get the fileName without extension. Then it's just string concatenation with what you already have. `-File` as parameter for `Get-ChildItem` to filter only files.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have found indeed only handles .jpg files, because it uses the filter `*.jpg`.

If you want all files in the folder to have the LastWriteTime appended to the file name, use

```
$folder = 'D:\Test'  # set this to the path where the files are
(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File) | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notmatch '_\d{12}$' } |  # skip files that already have the date appended
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}_{1:ddMMyyyyHHmm}{2}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Extension }
```